# How to say phrases "Can you repeat that" and "can we go to the next question"?

Tags: grammar, politeness, questions

I have a speaking exam coming up and I'm feeling mostly prepared, but after there's an unprepared conversation part which we're also graded on. It's with my teacher but luckily keigo isn't necessary.

I just want to make sure that for these phrases I'm using the correct level of politeness.

1. Could you please repeat that

   - "すみませんが、もう一度お願いします。" or "もう一度説明してくれますか"
2. Could we move on to the next question

   - "次の質問をしてもいいですか。"

Hopefully I wont have to use them but if I mess something up or mishear what my teacher asks I don't want the conversation to just fall apart.

Answer (score 3):

For 1, you could use one of the following:

> 「すみません、もう一度お願いします」
>   (すみませんが is okay too, but I wouldn't use it by default as it changes the tone quite a bit)
>
> 「すみません、上手く聞き取れませんでした」("Excuse me, I couldn't hear (/make out) what you
>   just said."
>
> 「すみません、もう一回言ってもらってもいいですか」（You can use 一度 here, too. It's interchangeable with 一回 in this context.)
>
> 「すみません、もう一度言ってください」 (More direct. You might want to avoid using this one too much.)
>
> 「すみません、もう一回言ってくれませんか」
>
> 「質問を繰り返していただけませんか」 ("Could you repeat the question?")

For "please explain one more time" I would suggest using 
「もう一度説明してくれませんか」 instead of 「くれますか」, since the former is more often used when asking a favor. It's like "Would you explain that again?" vs "Will you explain that again?" You also might want to preface it with 上手く聞き取れませんでした。

For 2, you could use the example you gave if you're the one asking the questions, or

> 「次の質問をお願いします」

if it's your teacher who is asking the questions.